# Efficiently reconstruct DataFrame using oversampled index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames: df1 and df2

both df1 and df2 are derived from the same original data set, which has a DatetimeIndex.

df2 still has a DatetimeIndex.

Whereas, df1 has been oversampled and now has an int index with the prior DatetimeIndex as a 'Date' column within it.

I need to reconstruct a df2 so that it aligns with df1, i.e. I'll need to oversample the rows that are oversampled and then order them and set them onto the same int index that df1 has.

Currently, I'm using these two functions below, but they are painfully slow. Is there any way to speed this up? I haven't been able to find any built-in function that does this. Is there?

```
def align_data(idx_col,data):
    new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=idx_col.index,columns=data.columns)
    for label,group in idx_col.groupby(idx_col):
        if len(group.index) > 1:
            slice = expanded(data.loc[label],len(group.index)).values
        else:
            slice = data.loc[label]
        new_data.loc[group.index] = slice
    return new_data

def expanded(row,l):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[row for i in np.arange(l)],index=np.arange(l),columns=row.index)
```

A test can be generated using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
dt_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-01',end='2018-07-02',freq='B')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((len(dt_idx),20)),index=dt_idx)
df1.index.name = 'Date'
df2 = df1.copy()
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df1.sample(len(dt_idx)/2)],axis=0)
df1.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
t = dt.datetime.now()
df2_aligned = align_data(df1['Date'],df2)
print(dt.datetime.now()-t)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it looks like ``align_data`` is an attempt to reconstruct a left join.  If so, perhaps ``df1.merge(df2, left_on='Date', right_index=True, how='left')`` will work.

Comment: @DoDoSmarts thanks! yea, it is basically a join but without the records of the left dataframe. An outer join of them and then selecting only the columns from the right dataframe works much better. Thanks a lot!